# Ajax: Simultaneous loading of multiple images

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, user-interface

I have a grid of pictures (3x3, side by side, laid out in a ). I need to update this grid every so often. Since every picture independent from the rest (they get grabbed from different locations), I elected to load every picture by its own ajax callback, like so:

```
for (var i=0; i < numPictures; i++) {
  Dajaxice.loadPicture(callback_loadPicture, {'picture_id':i})
}
```

The function callback_loadPicture() puts the picture into its proper place in the .

The problem is: Often, even though some picture will finish loading sooner than others, the browser will not display anything until the last ajax call is finished. Since some calls can time out, this means that I don't see anything until that single picture times out.

This behaves slightly differently in every browser: sometimes the picture will show as the callbacks finish (but usually not), sometimes the browser will show some images, but postpone showing all until the last one is finished loading.

I am using:

- django 1.3 (python 2.7)
- windows x64 as (test) server
- dajaxice for ajax implementation

I am open to changing the structure of my code.

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: So you're seeing this behavior in development, presumably while using the runserver management command? The Django development web server is single-threaded: it can only handle one request at a time. So unlike with a production web server, each AJAX call is blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ajax calls are blocking as said by chrisdpratt, if you really need to display the images at the same time I would advise some kind of preloading of the 3x3 grid of images and when required by the code you can display them.

With this in mind you can run the code you already have on `$(document).ready()` but make the images hidden (ie `display:none`). When later required you would just change the display attribute on the images you need to display.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue you were seeing was indeed caused by the single-threaded implementation of the Django development server, you might try `django-devserver` (https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver).  Amongst other improvements, it boasts:

*"An improved runserver allowing you to process requests simultaneously."*

The other improvements make it worth it, too!